# Are Variance Estimates from the Restricted Maximum Likelihood Considered as Unique?

Tags: regression

I understand that Maximum Likelihood Estimation (MLE) can sometimes result in Biased Estimates - for example, when estimating parameters of the Normal Distribution, MLE is known to produce biased estimates of $\sigma^2$:

\begin{aligned}
\ell(\mu, \sigma^2 | \mathbf{y}) &= \log\left[\prod_{i=1}^{n}f(y_i; \mu, \sigma^2)\right] \
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n}\log f(y_i; \mu, \sigma^2) \
&
\end{aligned}

\begin{aligned}
\frac{d}{d\sigma^2}\ell(\mu, \sigma^2 | \mathbf{y}) = 0
\end{aligned}

\begin{aligned} Bias =
\mathbb{E}\left(|\hat{\sigma}^2_{\text{MLE}} - \sigma^2|\right) &= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i - \bar{y})^2 - \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i - \bar{y})^2 \neq 0\end{aligned}

To target this problem, a modification of MLE called Restricted Maximum Likelihood Estimation (RMLE) can be used in which we calculate the Likelihood for a transformed (random) variable $k^\top y$, such that $k^\top x = 0$ and $k^\top  = I - X(X^\top X)^{-1}X^\top$ .

For example, in the case of a Linear Mixed Effects Model: $$y = X\beta + Z u + e$$

$$(u,e)^\top \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\begin{Bmatrix}0 \\ 0\end{Bmatrix}, \sigma^2\begin{Bmatrix} G & 0 \\ 0 & R \end{Bmatrix}  \right)$$

$$\operatorname{Var}(y) = \sigma^2(ZGZ^\top + R) = \sigma^2 H$$

In this case, the regular Log-Likelihood for $Y$ can be written as:

$$\mathcal{l}_{\text{ML}}(\beta, \phi;y) = -\frac{1}{2}\left(n\log(2\pi) + n\log(\sigma^2) + \log|\mathbf{H}| + (\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta})^\top \mathbf{H}^{-1} (\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta})/\sigma^2\right)$$

However, variance estimates from this regular Log-Likelihood function might be biased.

On the other hand, the Restricted Maximum Log-Likelihood for $k^\top y$ can be written as:

$$\mathbf{K}^\top \mathbf{y} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2 \mathbf{K}^\top \mathbf{H} \mathbf{K})$$

$$l_{\text{R}}(\phi; \mathbf{K}^\top \mathbf{y})_\ = -\frac{1}{2} \left((n-p)\log(2\pi) + (n-p)\log\sigma^2 + \log|\mathbf{K}^\top \mathbf{H}^{-1} \mathbf{K}| + \frac{1}{\sigma^2} \mathbf{y}^\top \mathbf{K} (\mathbf{K}^\top \mathbf{H}^{-1} \mathbf{K})^{-1} \mathbf{K}^\top \mathbf{y}\right)$$

**This brings me to my question:** I have read that sometimes terms such as $(\mathbf{K}^\top \mathbf{H}^{-1} \mathbf{K})^{-1}$ and $(X^\top X)^{-1}$
might be difficult to invert - for instance, sometimes the "ranks" of these matricies results in these terms being non-invertible.

In such instances, a "Generalized Inverse" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse) can be used to invert these matrices . However, I remember from my Linear Algebra class that the Generalized Inverse is not always "unique" - that is, for some matrix $A$, there might exist several possible Generalized Inverses.

**Thus, if a portion of the Restricted Log Likelihood is not unique, will this complicate the estimation of the Variance components?** For instance, if the Variance components due to  parts of the Likelihood being non-invertible are non-unique - could this result in a Non-Identifiable model?

If I have understood this correctly, the Restricted Maximum Likelihood was designed to target a problem of biased estimates - but ironically might result in another problem of non-identifiable estimates?

Thanks!

**References:**

- https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002437951100320X
- [Restricted maximum likelihood with less than full column rank of $X$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203216/restricted-maximum-likelihood-with-less-than-full-column-rank-of-x)

Comment: Focusing on getting the inversions done, I would suggest regularization: $\left(X^\textrm{T}X + \lambda I \right)^{-1}$, although this introduces bias.  I'm a Bayesian (mostly), so I don't have these problems :)

Comment: In general you can't simply replace an inverse with a pseudo-inverse and hope it will work (sometimes it does, but not always). If  you get an ambiguous likelihood then clearly it doesn't. (Even within an unidentifiable model, the likelihood of a given parameter value must be unique).